# Question on topic publication

Tags: ros, navigation, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to create some sort of base_controller for my motors in C++. I have two question about topics that I cannot answer for now.

First, if I read a message on the cmd_vel topic for example using a subscriber does the message I just read "disappeared" from the topic. Meaning if another Node try to read it, is the previously read message "gone" ?

Second, depending on the answer to the first question, how can I know if their is a steady stream of command coming from the cmd_vel topic ? Meaning if the message is erased when I read it how can I know that it was not 'outdated" or when to stop ?
If it is not erase by reading but rather by if their more new information, how can two node send data on the same topic ?

To try to be clearer here is a situation example :

Let's say I publish a Twist for my robot to go forward on the cmd_vel for 3 second and I publish no stop Twist after those 3 seconds.

- What is my subscriber to this topic going to read during the 3 first second and after ?
- Same question but what if my subscriber is a little bit slow and start reading 1 second after I start publishing the twists ?

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142121/question-on-topic-publication/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-03-19**:
when you publish a msg on a topic you give it an buffer to keep how many msgs in buffer and when you want to subscribe a msg you give it another buffer to keep how many msg in buffer. if you want to have two subscriber in
one topic you can use header to separate msgs.

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-19**:
If I publish one message, then I read it with my subscriber how can I know that there is no more input in the topic ? My question is more oriented at understanding how for example, turtlebot is able to know that the input is not steady.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want the last message on a topic to be "remembered" and getting sent to new subscribers, [latching a topic](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Publisher_Options) provides that capability.

To keep track of when messages arrive, you can update a "last_received" timestamp inside the topic callback (for example your "cmd_vel" callback). This way, your node always knows when the last message arrived. You can then have a [Timer](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Timers) running and in it´s callback check if the "last_received" timestamp is within a tolerance threshold of current time. If it is not, you send a motor stop command.
That´s one way of doing things. You could also use Threads, but using Timers and callbacks appears easier.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-20**:
That's what I was searching about. The timer and time stamp technique seems perfect.